# Android Studio stuck while building application

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I recently switched from Eclipse to Android Studio because I read that it is now the official IDE for Android application development. I downloaded and installed the latest version (1.0.2) for Windows. When using the program for the first time, I decided to create a test application to see if the program was working correctly. Unfortunately, it was not. Once I clicked the finish button to complete the New Project Wizard, A loading bar showed up that said `Gradle: Build`. This is where the program gets stuck. There is no error message and it appears that the program is running fine, however the build never actually completes. I am never given my *MainActivity.Java* class, or my *activitymain.xml* document. If I click the cancel button, the program freezes and I have to use the TaskManager to kill the program. If I re-enter the program and choose to open an existing project, my project will be there. However, upon trying to open the project, I am greeted with the same `Gradle: Build` loading bar.. I have been searching for an answer for the last 3 days and nothing has worked. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Things I have tried:

- Simply letting the program sit for a while to see if it was actually downloading something and was just really slow. I let it sit for 45+ minutes before killing the program.
- Uninstalling and re-installing Android Studio
- Restarting my computer
- Turning off my firewall (Kaspersky)
- Running the program as an administrator
- Connecting to a different network
- Disconnecting my computer from any networks (to force the program to build in offline mode)
- Manually downloading Gradle from the link that Android Studio attempts to use when it gets stuck and telling the program to use that file instead of downloading another one. 
  (I went to this link https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip, downloaded the file, unzipped it, went to Gradle settings in Android Studio, checked the *Offline work* checkbox, and finally set the *service directory path* to my unzipped Gradle folder.)

Hopefully I have given enough information and made it clear what my problem is. If not please tell me what else I need to explain so I can get this issue resolved. Thanks!

- Please note I am working on a 64 bit machine running Windows 8. Also, I use studio64.exe
  to run the program.

Comment: Can you please try build from the command line and post the output

Comment: You wouldn't mind guiding me through that would you? Kinda new to programming. @stevebot

Comment: ok, how about this, can you post the output from the gradle console window in Android Studio?

Comment: Gradle console is empty :(  @stevebot

Comment: ok try going to the terminal window in Android studio and then typing gradle tasks. This will give you a list of tasks that you can run.

Comment: Command line won't take "gradle tasks" - 'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. @stevebot

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion we had in the comments, it does not look like you have your gradle on your windows path.

Please change the below to point to your gradle install:

```
set GRADLE_HOME=C:\<installation location>\gradle-1.11
set PATH=%PATH%;%GRADLE_HOME%\bin
```

After this, verify that in the terminal running the following works:

```
gradle tasks
```

once you get this working, you will want to run the following in your project:

```
gradle wrapper
```

This will produce a `.bat` file which you can then use to run gradle through the wrapper, letting you support multiple native gradle installations.

Comment: How do I set GRADLE_HOME and PATH? Are those enviroment variables?

Comment: @JayBoe yes they are environment variables

Comment: Ok, got all the command line stuff working! Where is the batch file now? And do I just run it or do I have to so something else with it? @stevebot

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to create an application through Android Studio again. It looks like Android Studio was not able to function because gradle was not installed on your path. I believe now it should allow you to create projects without issue.

Comment: Do you think it would still take a couple mins to do the Gradle: build?? Or is the thing stuck again?

Comment: no it should be quick, and there should be logs in either the gradle console or event log.